# GitHub integration error "cannot verify team membership"

Tags: drone.io

I have launched a `drone/drone:0.8` using docker, and providing these environment variables:

```
DRONE_ADMIN=stevecrozz
DRONE_GITHUB=true
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=...
DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=...
DRONE_OPEN=true
DRONE_ORGS=myorg
```

When I attempt to log in, I get:

```
msg="cannot verify team membership for ."
```

I was expecting to be logged in since I am a member of 'myorg' on github. It isn't clear to me what I can do to troubleshoot from here.

Comment: Hard to tell you the issue but I would recommend you to try to double check your Github client/secret scope/permissions might be the cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it turned out that the Github OAuth application had not yet been approved by 'myorg' on Github. Once an administrator approved the application, I was able to successfully log into my drone application and use it.